# start erlang/elixir on a defined interface ip address

Tags: networking, erlang, elixir, httpoison

I'm using elixir to make some XMLRPC queries to an host on my machine that accepts only call from 127.0.x.y where x and y can be configurable but the ip can not be 127.0.0.1.

Simple `curl` requests to this host would fail unless I add the flag `--interface 127.0.x.y`.

How can I start my elixir application with a given interface ip different from 127.0.0.1?

The library I use to send the request is HTTPoison if this can be helpful.

Comment: Does this work (with the correct URL and IP): `HTTPoison.get "http://localhost:8000/", [], [hackney: [connect_options: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}]]]`?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I spent a whole day to find that option on `hackney` documentation and source code... If you transform your comment into an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass `ip` in the `connect_options` to `hackney`. `hackney` passes `connect_options` directly to `gen_tcp`, which accepts an `ip`:

```
HTTPoison.get("http://...", [], [hackney: [connect_options: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}]]])
```